# Aggregating Fiscal Week data into monthly sum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
      YR_FW    YIELD
0    201401     12.3
1    201402     10.2
2    201403     7.2
3    201404     8.0
4    201405     1.2
...  ....     ....
96   201446     102.3
97   201447     101.7
98   201448     89.5
99   201449     72.2
100  201450     88.0
101  201451     98.89
```

I would like to aggregate (sum) such that I have 12 months. It may look something like this:

```
Months    Summed_YLD
1            value
2            value
...         ...
11           value
12           value
```

Note: The YR_FW at times have missing values. For example `201427` is not in the data frame.

Note2: If cases overlap, they should be aggregated to ending month. The week starts with Monday and ends with Sunday (this is not a 5-day week).

Comment: What should happen in the cases where a week overlaps two months? Should the values be aggregated to the starting month? Ending month? Divided between the two?

Comment: Another clarification:  What day of the week are your weeks starting on?

Comment: @root: Those are very good questions. If the cases overlap two weeks, you would aggregate to ending month. The week ends with Sunday so starts on Monday. I will add this to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert these to datetimes first:

```
In [11]: df["YR_FW"] = pd.to_datetime(df["YR_FW"].astype("str") + "-0", format="%Y%W-%w")

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
       YR_FW  YIELD
0 2014-01-12   12.3
1 2014-01-19   10.2
2 2014-01-26    7.2
3 2014-02-02    8.0
4 2014-02-09    1.2
```

Note that the `%W` specifies that the week starts on Monday, and the `'-0'` specifies to take the Sunday within the week. So, the resulting dates would be the last day of the week specified.

Now you can use the `dt` accessor to extract the last day of the week's month:

```
In [13]: df.groupby(df["YR_FW"].dt.month).sum()
Out[13]:
       YIELD
YR_FW       
1       29.7
2        9.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please note that the "YR_FW" is the weekly value. Hence, 201402 is the second week of January and not the month of February. I would like to combine the 52 weeks into 12 months.

Comment: @Rohit hmmm, it seems like %W or %U should do that, but it doesn't seem to work for me :/ https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @Rohit Ah ha, you need to do: `pd.to_datetime(df["YR_FW"].astype("str") + "-0", format="%Y%W-%w")` Note: astype may not be necessary.

Comment: Yes, I had to change the type to `str` before it could work. However, how does this address the following questions: (1) what happens when the week overlaps two months. How does it aggregate? (2) When there is a missing week?  These questions are asked by root above and very pertinent in order to get the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: The `to_datetime` conversion in @AndyHayden's comment is correct.  The `%W` specifies that the week starts on Monday, and the `'-0'` specifies to take the Sunday within the week.  So, the resulting dates would be the last day of the week specified.  Then, when doing the `groupby` as in his answer, it would aggregate to the ending month.

Comment: @AndyHayden: I've edited your answer to reflect the changes you made in the comments.  Feel free to further edit it if any of the wording is off.

Comment: @root: Thank you so much for your help along with Andy. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have enough data to fully check the code, but this is what I arrived to right now. If we suppose that we have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"YR_FW":[201401,201402,201403,201405,201506],"YIELD":[12.3,10.2,7.2,1.2,3.8]})

     YR_FW    YIELD
0    201401     12.3
1    201402     10.2
2    201403     7.2
3    201405     1.2
4    201506     3.8
```

with the 3rd row missing to conform to your actual data, and a different year added. We could proceed as follow:

```
df_pd_range = pd.period_range("01/01/2014","02/07/2016", freq="W") #Here you place the period of your data, I elongated till 2016 to test code
df.YR_FW = df.YR_FW.astype(str).map(lambda a_: a_[:4] + "-" + a_[4:])
a_ = [np.logical_and(df_pd_range.year == int(df.YR_FW.iloc[i][:4]),df_pd_range.week==int(df.YR_FW.iloc[i][5:])) for i in range(len(df))] #choose only the period that is present in the data
b_ = [df_pd_range[i][0] for i in a_]
arrays = [[i.year for i in b_],[i.month for i in b_] ]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=["year", "month"])
df.set_index(index, inplace=True)
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).mean() #Here you obtain mean data grouped by week and year
```

Tell me how it goes

Comment: Thank you for working this out. I wanted everything in pandas which Andy's answer does. It is also very elegant. Thanks nonetheless for your effort!